# Bootstrap mobile header alignment issues

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to figure out something I think should be simple but I can't seem to get it to work properly.  I have a design I am trying to follow and can't seem to get it to align correctly.

This is what I want it to look like.

[image: screenshot]

My problem is it will not align anything like what I want.  I have gone through a bunch of different ways and this is my latest attempt and figure I will ask for some frontend help.  home button is just a link.  Search button will open up a div with search field not coded yet in example below.  Hamburger menu will open up other header links.

Here is where I got and you can see how it is not really close.

http://jsbin.com/fucozulecu/edit?html,css,output

css

```
   .navbar-nav {
      float: none;
      text-align: center;
    }

.navbar-nav li {
  float: none;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 33%;
  color: white;
}
```

html

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse" role="navigation">
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li>
                <a href="/">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle btn-home visible-sm visible-xs">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></span>
                    </button>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle btn-search" data-toggle="collapse"
                        data-target=".navbar-search">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
                </button>
            </li>
            <li>
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-menubuilder">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-menubuilder">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <b class="caret"></b></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-search">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-search">
            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->

</nav>
```

Any help would be appreciated as I am guessing this is fairly easy for more expereinced front end devs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using bootstrap, I added the bootstrap grid classes and rearranged the home button.

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav row">
    <li class="col-xs-4">
             <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle btn-home visible-sm visible-xs">
                        <a href="/" class="nav-btn"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></span>    </a>
            </button>
    </li>
    <li class="col-xs-4">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle nav-btn" data-toggle="collapse"
                data-target=".navbar-search">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
        </button>
    </li>
    <li class="col-xs-4">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-menubuilder">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Woking example http://jsbin.com/quxawovude/1/edit?html,css,output